# Filling PHP array with "for" loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, population

I'm trying to populate an array in PHP as following :

```
<?php

$maxPages = 20;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxPages; $i++) {

    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/?page='.$i;

    $targets =  array(
            $url => array(
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
            ),
    );

}

print_r($targets);

?>
```

However it only seems to display the last populated value:

```
Array
(
[http://127.0.0.1/?page=20] => Array
    (
        [13] => 10
    )

)
```

I also tried changing : " $targets = " to " $targets[] = " however it produces this output :

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [http://127.0.0.1/?page=0] => Array
            (
                [13] => 10
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [http://127.0.0.1/?page=1] => Array
            (
                [13] => 10
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [http://127.0.0.1/?page=2] => Array
            (
                [13] => 10
            )

    )
```

While my desired output is :

```
Array
(
[http://127.0.0.1/?page=0] => Array
    (
        [13] => 10
    )

[http://127.0.0.1/?page=1] => Array
    (
        [13] => 10
    )

[http://127.0.0.1/?page=2] => Array
    (
        [13] => 10
    )
```

)

Probably an easy fix but I'm unable to see it. 
Can someone with more knowledge point me out my mistake ?

Thanks !

Comment: `$targets[] = ...` you're reassigning the `$targets` variable in each loop rather than adding to it

Comment: I tried that as well, but it also does not give me the correct output, see updated question.

Comment: In that case you want `$targets[$url] = array(CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code :

```
$maxPages = 20;
$targets = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxPages; $i++) {

    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/?page='.$i;

        $targets[$url] =  array(
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
        );

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($targets);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as changing the loop body to:

```
$targets[] =  array( // <-- NOTE THE []
        $url => array(
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
        ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

```
$targets[] = array(
        $url => array(
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
        ),
);
```

Use `[]` to append the array to `$targets` instead of overwriting.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

```
$targets = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxPages; $i++) {

  $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/?page='.$i;

  **$targets[]** =  array(
        $url => array(
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
        ),
  );

}
```

use targets[] to create a new array each loop

Answer (score 0):

So from what we deduced in the comments: Your first issue is that you're reassigning the `$targets` variable in the loop rather than appending to the array using the `[]` notation.

Then we discovered that you need to set the key of `$targets` to be `$url` so that's easily fixed by adding `$url` into the square brackets `[$url]`. Which gives us:

```
$targets[$url] = array(
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution